# AutoMapper error after upgrading to .NET 7

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, upgrade, .net-7.0

I upgraded a .NET Core 2.1 app to .NET 7 and upgraded the AutoMapper version that was being used to the latest version.

I had to change the `ResolveUsing` calls to `MapFrom` as the earlier was not available in the new version of the AutoMapper.

Now when I run the app, I am getting the following error:

> Error: Method not found: '!!1 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(!!0)'.

I have found that it's happening to Methods that are using the automapper where it's using a custom method:

.ForMember(dest => dest.RoleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => CustomResolvers.GetRoleName(src)))

The above CustomResolvers is a static public class and GetRoleName is a static method. This was fine using ResolveUsing in the earlier version of automapper but changing to MapFrom, causes the above mentioned error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Angelo

Comment: I search about this error, In most cases it is caused by inappropriate version , But you are using the latest version...

Comment: which version of Automapper you are using?

Comment: Hi Jalpesh, its 12.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just that a project that I was referencing was using the Automapper and that had the older version of Automapper.

Once I updated the Automapper for that project, everything is fine.

Thanks
Angelo